# Sort result based on Parent Child Connection in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a table with following structure. The last column parentID is obviously a connection to other row. If no parent exist that will be 0. But there wont be a third level hierarchy. That means if one row having any parent, it never will hold any child.

```
ID    |   Test Name    |    ParentID
-------------------------------------
1     |      A         |       0
2     |      B         |       0
3     |      Z         |       2
4     |      L         |       2
5     |      D         |       2
6     |      E         |       0
7     |      Q         |       2
8     |      R         |       6
9     |      S         |       2
10    |      J         |       6
-----------------------------------------------
```

Hope the structure is clear. So I need a query that will return all rows, but that will sort all rows based on testname, but that must keep the hierarchy too.

So the result of the query should be

```
ID    |   Test Name    |    ParentID
-------------------------------------
1     |      A         |       0
2     |      B         |       0
5     |      D         |       2
4     |      L         |       2
7     |      Q         |       2
9     |      S         |       2
3     |      Z         |       2
6     |      E         |       0
10    |      J         |       6
8     |      R         |       6
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
order by case when ParentID = 0
           then ID
           else ParentID
         end,
         ParentID,
         [Test Name]
```